# Gatsby routing and dynamic urls

Tags: dynamic, gatsby, url-routing, cloudflare

Scenario: I have a Gatsby site hosted on Cloudflare Pages and custom domains managed by Cloudflare.
I deploy the Gatsby site to two places with some config to change settings, colours etc.

I have a results page that sits in `pages/search-results/[..].tsx` which allows me to locally run pages such as /search-results/2023-06-06/, the date bit is dynamic and the components on that page hit an api when the page loads.

What I am struggling with is how to get this page to work across different domains which have different urls structure.

- Site 1 - domain1.com/date-results/{date}
- Site 2 - domain2.com/shop-results/{date}

Both need to use the same page under the hood (search-results/index.html)

I have a transform rule in Cloudflare which, in the attached example looks for anything on `tom-test/` and rewrites to `search-results/`
[image]

If I then go to tom-test/foo, I get the Gatsby 404 page.

If I turn JS off, then I get a blank page. With with JS on, I get the 404 page.

What I expect to happen is for me to see the search-results/index.html page which does exist.

If I change the 'Rewrite to' path to be empty, then it goes to the root/index.html (home) page which I expect.

What am I doing wrong and/or how can I resolve this? Thanks